# Prestashop unstable in Amazon AWS + RDS even with a super-configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-rds, prestashop

We have right now about 800 users simultaneously online in the website, that is unstable since 3 hours ago, when the client made an publicity with an influencer on instagram.

Server:
Apache2
PHP 7.0
MariaDB

AWS: m5.2xlarge (monitoring print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1kQG.jpg)
RDS: db.m5.24xlarge (monitoring print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGkg2.jpg)

Somebody has any ideia why the website is still unstable? Slow and sometimes offline?

Comment: Did you check CPU/Memory/diskIO utilization?

Comment: You need to add a cache module and a CDN to absord that kind of things, Prestashop core is not supposed to handle that much people without proper cache. Actually 800 people in less than 10 minutes is a pretty bigger deal than most of eCommerce might face in their lifetime.

What version do you use ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt! The website is already using CloudFlare as a CDN to images, CSS and scripts + a cache plugin is installed. We are using Express Cache 3 plugin.

Comment: Dusan, thanks for your answer! CPU, Memory and Disk IO are been shown in the pictures I attached. Everything normal, I think.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems that your AWS instances could perfectly handle such traffic.

**Your performance issues might be related to some SQL-lock behavior:**

- Check whether you are using InnoDB or MyISAM tables, prefer InnoDB, you can [switch easily](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/convert-myisam-to-innodb/)
- Turn on [slow_query_log in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/slow-query-log-overview/) and monitor what's happening, a module or specific query might be the one causing your troubles

**Here are some other performance improvements you could consider:**

- Using Nginx + PHP-FPM rather than Apache
- Using PHP 7.3 rather than PHP 7.0 (~15% performance boost on PrestaShop), this will just require a few PHP warnings to fix
- Enabling and tuning the PHP Opcache (already in PHP 7.x, simply [configure it in php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php))
- Using two separate MariaDB instances, with a Master/slave configuration (you can specify the two servers in the PrestaShop configuration)
- Using [mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) to find the optimal MariaDB configuration
- Using a caching module

Comment: Bruno, with 'using a caching module', do you mean with a prestashop addon or what? Thanks